# How to map static properties to RDBMS

Tags: mysql, sql, static, rdbms

I have:

```
class Settings{
   static int temperature;
}
```

Tables roughly corrospond to object **instances** how do you represent **static data**

What's is a correct way to implementing this kind of behaviour in an RDBMS ?

Answer (score 0):

This type of mapping is one of the conceptual and technical difficulties that are often encountered when a relational database management system is being used by a program written in an object-oriented programming language.
A major mismatch between existing relational and OO languages is the type system differences. The relational model strictly prohibits by-reference attributes, whereas OO languages embrace and expect by-reference behavior. Scalar types and their operator semantics can be vastly different between the models, causing problems in mapping.
It has been argued, by [Christopher J. Date](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christopher_J._Date) and others that a native mapping between classes and relational schema is a fundamental design mistake

See Object [relational impedance mismatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_impedance_mismatch).

Comment: so is it impossible to map it in a sensible way ?

Comment: Can you show us that in which use-case you will need to save this data inside a table?

Comment: I have global settings for my app , and i want to save them on MySQL with the abllity for the user to change them. as you can see it doesnt make sense to talk about instances of global settings

Comment: IMO having a table for the settings with only update permission for the user will solve the problem. (insert and delete being forbidden)

Comment: a single table row is a solution but it doesnt seem appropriate. it's anagolous to a singleton

Comment: Why a single row? have a row per setting. Do you have only one setting field called temperature?

Comment: what if you have a string and an int ?

Comment: Have a table with these columns, SETTINGS("ID","NAME","TYPE","DESCRIPTION"), TYPE could have these data (1=string , 2= int , ...) could be achieved with check-constraint